# How to send a message in MQL4/5 from MetaTrader Terminal to python using ZeroMQ?

Tags: python, zeromq, mql4, mql5

I just want to send a message from MetaTrader Terminal, using it`s MQL4/5 to Python, just a simple client server, in which MQL4/5 is a client that sends, and python is a server who receives and these two are syncing with ZeroMQ.

The Python side code is this which I am sure this part is working fine:

```
    import zmq
    import time


    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:9999")

    print("Server Started")
    while True:
        message = socket.recv()              # Wait for next request from client
        print("Received request: ", message)
        time.sleep (1)
        socket.send_string("World")
```

the MQL4/5 side is this:

```
   Context context( "helloworld" );
   Socket socket( context, ZMQ_REQ );

   Print( "Connecting to hello world server…" );
   socket.connect( "tcp://127.0.0.1:9999" );

   while ( True )
   {
      ZmqMsg request( "Hello" );
      socket.send( request );

      ZmqMsg reply;
      socket.recv( reply );           // Get the reply.

      Sleep( 1000 );
   }
```

it seems like MQL4/5 doesn't send anything.
Can you say what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

> *Can you say what is wrong with it?*

### A few things to start with on MQL4/5-side :

MetaTrader Terminal can operate the compiled MQL4/5 language in several, quite  different code-execution modes.

If this was tried in **`Script`**, the damages are less cardinal than if this would be in **`ExpertAdvisor`** and worst side-effects would happen if this was run in some **`CustomIndicator`** -type-of-MQL4/5-code.

---

### On ZeroMQ-side :

In any case, **`REQ/REP`** Built-in Scalable Formal Communication Archetype pattern is a worst case choice, as in many previous posts, there has been explained how fragile this built-in was and that it can easily fall into a principally un-salvageable mutual dead-lock juxtaposition, so better re-read these posts and try to avoid this risk before going into production-grade service desing and implementation.

Always setup **`socket.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )`**, **both** on MQL4/5 and Python sides. No exceptions, no excuse.

A setup with **`socket.setsockopt( zmq.COMPLETE, 1 )`**, **both** on MQL4/5 and Python sides is also more than adviseable.

---

### ZeroMQ language-specific bindings for MQL4/5 :

As there are several active bindings available for MQL4/5 **`#import`**-ed mediations between MetaTrader Terminal MQL4/5 code-execution ecosystem and the ZeroMQ API v.X.Y.Z DLL-library, there is not possible ATM to go into more details. Having used API v2.1.11 ( I had modified the **`.MQH`**-file for solving **`#import`**-ed interface incompatibilities introduced into the game with *New*-**`MQL4.56789`** changed game - as **`string`** actually stopped being a **`string`** and some others ) and having seen other bindings, up to the ZeroMQ API v.4.2.+, there are differences to know about in detail, if going beyond a just "**`Helloworld`**"-example.

Yet, **`Context()`** instance initiation ought be equipped with appropriate settings / parameters and when testing, your code should routinely acquire all return-codes + handle all exceptions programmatically ( at least **`Print()`** them into log for further debugging with **FILE** and **LINE** ).

Also use **`#import`**-ed function **`int aZmqERROR = zmq_errno();`**, wherever your doubts may spring out, so as to know there was no ZeroMQ error state related right before / after a call took place, or to know exactly what was ZeroMQ signalling from its internal layers, that may have prevented an API call to deliver an expected functional state / result.  An MQL4/5-side **`string Zmq::errorMessage( int error )`** is ready to advice on some more human readable hints on observing any such ZeroMQ-side error-flag.

---

### Last, but not least :

also check the localhost FireWall-configuration, if the TCP **`port# == 9999`** was actually free to be used, or if the administrative bans on the FireWall security policies did actually prevent any attempt from successfully going and use this port#.

Until validated in public, better terminate each **`Context()`**-instance explicitly and with due care ( after having explicitly **`.close()`**-ed all locally created ZeroMQ-**`Socket()`**-instances. Nasty things could have happended in the earlier API versions, so better be systematic and defensive in all newer API-versions, even if examples or posted code does not do this systematically.